# open source flash?

Tags: flash

Is there a open source alternative to flash. I love to create flash games but flash is very expensive :(.

Comment: Eventually SVG/HTML5 will serve the same purpose

Comment: is it possible to create 2d games in html5 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are talking about the IDE, I would recomend [FlashDevelop](http://www.flashdevelop.org/wikidocs/index.php?title=Main_Page) using Flex SDK to compile. You will have to code everything with ActionScript, so no Timelines or any of the FLash IDE goodness (or badness if you like :) ). Here is a tutorial on how to get started:

http://abrahamyan.com/2008/11/28/how-to-setup-flashdevelop/

Also have a look at [Haxe](http://haxe.org/), it integrates seamlessly with FlashDevelop and you can generate swf files with it.